# Can a const object modify a value of unowned non-const object?

Tags: c++, pointers, const-correctness

```
struct SomeStruct {
  int value;
  void set_value(int i) {
    value = i;
  }
};

struct SomeOtherStruct {
  SomeOtherStruct(SomeStruct* some_struct){
    unowned_struct = some_struct;
  }

  void modify_struct(int i) const {
    unowned_struct->set_value(i);
  }

  SomeStruct* unowned_struct;
};

int main() {
  SomeStruct some_struct;
  const SomeOtherStruct some_other_struct(&some_struct);
  some_other_struct.modify_struct(10);

  /*...*/
}
```

Here, I'm trying to modify a value of a non-const struct `SomeStruct` through an unowned pointer in a const struct `SomeOtherStruct`.

Is this valid code? AFAIU this compiles. But is this a defined behavior? Are there any potential risks?

Comment: What is an "unowned pointer"?

Comment: Cf.: `std::vector<int> vec{0}; const auto a = vec.begin(); *a = 4;`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt By "unowned pointer", I meant a pointer to a not owned object.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Be aware that this distinction is not part of the C++ core language though. Also note that if you want to model ownership, check out `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and all the utilities surrounding them!

Answer (score 2):

The `unowned_struct` is a pointer. Since it's a part of a `SomeOtherObject` constant, it is a constant pointer. However, it is not a "pointer to constant", so using it to modify the pointee is fine and doesn't even require a `const_cast` in order to do so.

The code is valid and has defined behaviour. There are potential risks though, as with any raw pointers and unclear owhership.